In Springboot how to configure http only response cookie (refresh token) from subdomain (api.example.com)
I have my frontend running on "https://example.com" and backend running on "https://api.example.com".
From backend, the login endpoint "https://api.example.com/auth/login" is returning refresh token in response headers as below (i can see it in browser network tab):
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://example.com
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Set-Cookie:  refreshToken=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9...; Path=/auth/refresh; Domain=example.com; Max-Age=31536000000; Expires=Thu, 23 Oct 3023 00:57:41 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax

other headers....

But when frontend makes the call to refresh access-token then request doesn't contain the refresh token. Browser doesn't append the token in the request and server rejects it with 403. Below are the request details for refresh token:
Request URL:https://api.example.com/auth/refresh
Request Method:POST
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Remote Address:xxxxx
Referrer Policy:strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Request Headers:
:authority:api.example.com
:method:POST
:path:/auth/refresh
:scheme:https
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Content-Length:0
Origin:https://example.com
Priority:u=1, i
Referer:https://example.com

Why browser is not appending or storing the refresh token when it is coming from same sub-domain and domain attribute is also set in refresh-token cookie?
The cookie is also not visible in browser's dev tool.

well it is not going to send you a refresh token if you are getting 403... You need to debug why you are getting unauthorized (403) and then hopefully you will get the cookie

@JAsgarov: Getting 403 is understood but the question is why browser not sending back refresh token cookie in refresh request?

oh i see i misunderstood the problem. The reason browser doesn't include the cookie is usualy because either 1. domain to which request is being made doesn't match the domain of the cookie exactly 2. secureFlag prevents cookies being sent with non https  connection 3. you are missing with crendentials. In your case most likely reason is domain (has to be an exact match). If you want cookie to be sent to subdomain as well you have to add . before domain => Cookie Domain: .example.com

Finally with "J Asgarov" answer, i was able to solve the issue. The cookie setup was ok as i was already setting domain "example.com" in it (there is no need of leading . in it anymore, browser allows for sub-domains as well if root matches).
The real issue was that i was setting withCredentials true only for refresh token request whereas it needed to be true for login request as well. After enabling it for login then browser was able to read the refresh token cookie otherwise it was getting ignored from login response.
As per web docs withCredentials flag is required for both outgoing request and incoming response. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials
